# How to Save and Load Data from internal memory, NOT SD, NOT SQL,NOT SHARED PREFERENCE

Tags: android, file-io, filesystems

Wow, I cant believe how many problems related to loading and saving to internal memory.
I find that I can only Save to a protected area related to my app. 
I am not sure I can even create a directory in that area.
Storing to the SD I've mastered, but the requirements are that if no sdcard is available or has been removed the app continues be able to load and save user settings.  I have 120 different data items so shared preferences are not the way. Cache is not persistent.

I currently have as a method :

```
public static void SaveUserPrefs()
{
 try
{
 //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("userPrefs.dat", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "userPrefs.dat"); 
 BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); //to get a buffered stream  
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
 oos.writeFloat(versionNumber);
 oos.writeInt(autoWifiStart);
 oos.writeInt(autoAirPlane);
 ... many more items and file close
```

I get file not found exceptiom /userPrefs.dat Read only file system
You would think the same code would work either external or internal, but doesnt.
I have tried the comment out code also with same results.
Where and how do I save this data?
And do I need to do something different to load it?
I do have permission set to save_external_Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find that I can only Save to a protected area related to my app.

On internal storage, this is correct.

> I am not sure I can even create a directory in that area.

Use `getFilesDir()` to retrieve a `File` object pointing to your application's area on internal storage, then call `mkdirs()` on the `File` object to create subdirectories. The latter is standard Java file I/O.

> I have 120 different data items so shared preferences are not the way.

There is no particular limit on the number of items in `SharedPreferences`. `SharedPreferences` are stored in an XML file.

> I get file not found exceptiom /userPrefs.dat Read only file system

You have supplied an invalid path. Use `getFilesDir()` to get the `File` object pointing to your application's area on internal storage, then use the appropriate `File` constructor to create a `File` object pointing to your specific file on internal storage. Use that latter `File` object in your `FileOutputStream` constructor. Again, other than `getFilesDir()`, this is standard Java file I/O.

> You would think the same code would work either external or internal, but doesnt

That code does not work with external storage, either, as the path you have supplied is not on external storage.

> Where and how do I save this data?

Personally, I would never use `ObjectOutputStream`. For 120 items, I would definitely consider a SQLite database, otherwise I would serialize my data to JSON or XML. Any of those options are easier to debug than `ObjectOutputStream`, IMHO.

> And do I need to do something different to load it?

You will need to construct the appropriate `File` object pointing to the file in question for use with some type of `InputStream`, following standard Java file I/O.

> I do have permission set to save_external_Storage.

`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is not necessary for writing to internal storage.

Comment: Being new to Java, but a  long time C programmer I find it hard to take the words expressed and place them into code as you indicate. Let me ask another question... When I create a file within the internal protected storage are there any apps that show this file? Perhaps I might have found the correct answer earlier and dismissed it as not being visible in Astro File Manager because its internal and protected and only visible to the app it belongs to?

Comment: @user1445716: "When I create a file within the internal protected storage are there any apps that show this file?" -- only if the user has rooted their phone (i.e., is able to run apps with Linux superuser privileges), and is running some file manager designed to examine the whole device.

Comment: Last question. Do I need to create the standard directory or does the directory get created as part of installing the app always as  /data/data/com.myapp.somewhere/files ?

Comment: Ok really last question: I am currently grabbing the InternalDirectory name in onCreate and storing it in a static variable. As :\n File temp = getFilesDir();
  InternalDirectory=String.format("%s",temp); \n In the Load file method I use :\n FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(InternalDirectory+"/userPrefs.dat"); \n Is there better way to handle grabbing internal directory name? Its working now... thanks for your help to this old noobie.

Comment: @user1445716: "Do I need to create the standard directory" -- the directory pointed to by `getFilesDir()` is automatically created for you. "Is there better way to handle grabbing internal directory name?" -- call `getFilesDir()` on any `Context` at the point you need it. Since it is just a `File` object, there is no particular memory leak risk for keeping it in a static data member, so you are probably OK with what you have, but I tend to just get the value when I need it.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. Though sometimes code example helps too. I probably had it working when I changed it to internal memory, but the first thing the app does is check to see if the files it needs are created if not then create them, which is where I got hung up. I looked in a file explorer app and it showed nothing. After realizing that it was protected space I started questioning and restored to earlier code and started testing the code rather than looking for a file. Thanks again.